# How to access a method with parameters?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, game-engine, dice

I am creating a Dice Game as a project in IntelliJ with Java and right now I have a method in the Game class, where I want to reset the Dice Cup in the beginning of the game. Therefore, I have created a method called resetDiceCup() and a method called startGame().
Right now, I am getting the error "Identifier expected" in startGame() and I think it has something to do with the parameters I use in resetDiceCup().
Is there any way to fix this?

```
public class Game{

public void startGame() {


    resetDiceCup( int doublets, int numOfDoublets);
    System.out.println("Willkommen zu diesem Würfelspiel. Los geht´s!");
    String[] playerNames = Print.multipleAnswers("Please insert the name of a player.");

    player = new Player[playerNames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++)
    {
        player[i] = new Player(playerNames[i]);
    }
    }

//to "refresh" the DiceCup before every new game
public void resetDiceCup(int doublets, int numOfDoublets) {


    int[] result = new int[numOfDices]; //amout of dices in the game as chosen by players
    sum = 0;
    doublets = 0;
    numOfDoublets = 0;
    sumWithDoublets = 0;

}
```

}

Comment: `resetDiceCup( int doublets, int numOfDoublets);` remove those two `int`s from the call (only there, not in the method declaration).

Comment: Also, you should declare them (and give them a value) inside your `startGame` method.